# R: Extracting row numbers from a dataframe into a vector based on column value

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vector, extract

I am using R and trying to remove rows with a negative value for the "trial" column of my prepareRunSwitch data frame by putting the row numbers into a vector, prac, which I will then use to extract the compliment rows into a new data frame. However, the prac vector always returns empty. Below is my code, not sure what I am missing. Any help/advice is welcome, thank you!

```
prac <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(prepareRunSwitch)){
  if(prepareRunSwitch[i, "trial"] > 0){
    prac <- append(prac, i)
  }
  return(prac)
}
```

Comment: You don't need a loop, just use `which` i.e. `which(prepareRunSwitch$trial > 0)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this without a loop to get the row index of logical vector with `which`

```
which(prepareRunSwitch$trial > 0)
```

---

The below should work if we extract the column and then index

```
prac <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(prepareRunSwitch)){
   if(prepareRunSwitch$trial[i] > 0){
     prac <- append(prac, i)
    }
    return(prac)
 }
```

As a reproducible example

```
prac <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) if(mtcars$carb[i] == 4) prac <- append(prac, i)
prac
#[1]  1  2  7 10 11 15 16 17 24 29
```

As a side note, it is better to replace `1:nrow` with `seq_len(nrow(`